# New laptop (15.10) won't copy region 2 DVDs

Tags: 15.10, dvd

I have a new ASUS laptop on which I successfully installed Ubuntu 15.10. I also have a very old cast-off laptop running 14.04LTS. If I insert a region 2 DVD into the old machine, then it recognises it as a Video DVD and a GUI pops up asks which application to launch. The new laptop doesn't do this, although it does for region 0 DVDs. The new laptop will play the region 2 disk fine if I launch VLC and select the disk manually. If I selected Brasero it won't copy as it says I am missing libdvdcss.so.2, which I am not, as I followed the procedure outlined in [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs)

> Ubuntu 15.10 and newer From Ubuntu 15.10 onwards, libdvd-pkg is
>   available to ease the installation of libdvdcss.
>       Install the libdvd-pkg package (no need to add third party repositories) via Synaptic or command line:  sudo apt-get install
>   libdvd-pkg
>       Follow libdvd-pkg's instructions to let it download, compile, and install libdvdcss.

The new laptop will copy region 0 DVDs with Brasero OK.

I am wondering if this is due to the actual DVD drives installed on the machines. lshw -C disk shows:

```
  ASUS Ubuntu 15.10 -won't copy region 2
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: DVDRAM GUE1N
       vendor: HL-DT-ST
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: AS00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc

OLD ADVENT Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - copies region 2
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD writer
       product: CD/DVDW TS-L632D
       vendor: TSSTcorp
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: TIR0
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

**or maybe there is something I could tweak in the software configuration to make my new machine ask which application to launch when I insert a region 2 DVD?**

I feel that this is at the root of the problem. All replies gratefully received.